# WiX: How to create a share for all users?

Tags: wix

I am using *WiX* to create an installer, and wish to share a folder during the installation process. I would like to grant permission to all users. I am using the following fragment:

```
<util:FileShare Id="MYSHARE" Name="MyShare" Description="Description of MyShare">
  <util:FileSharePermission GenericRead="yes" Read="yes" ReadAttributes="yes" User="Everyone" />
</util:FileShare>
```

I am getting a compile time error of:
"Unresolved reference to symbol 'User:Everyone' in section 'Product:{MY-GUID}'."

**Any suggestions on how to create a share for all users?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a Util:User element.  The FileSharePermission/@User is a reference to a User/@Id attribute.

Unfortunately, there are some design inconsistencies related to User attribute.  Usually it is a reference to User/@Id but sometimes it is just the user name... sad, yes.. but we haven't fixed it all yet.

Comment: @Brad Leach I really donno what was the conclusion or answer of this question..?

Comment: How can this be used to specify a group?